# Sorting based on the rules set by a string variable

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, c++11

In my hypothetical app, I receive a list of hotels from the server.

```
struct Hotel 
{
  std::string name;            // e.g. Hilton, Ritz
  int stars;                   // In range [0..5], 0 stands for "unrated"
  int freeRoomCount;           // Number of available rooms [0..N]
  int parkingPlacesAvailable;  // Number of parking places availalble [0..M]
}
std::vector<Hotel> hotels;
```

All these items are displayed in a simple List View.
I have to provide different types of sorting. The sorting rules are also dictated by the central server.

The sorting rules are as follows:

```
std::string sortingRules; 
// "s" - sort by stars count
// "f" - sort by free room count
// "p" - sort by parking places available
// The sortingRules string can be a combination of those values. E.g.:
// "ps" - first goes who has the most number of parking places available, 
//        then goes hotels who has more stars
// More combinations available:
//  "s", "sf", "fp", "pf", "spf", "" etc. 
// (16 possible combinations, the empty string means alphabetical sorting)
```

So the question is: how to interpret this in C++? Enums and bit mask values doesn't work since they do not provide the 'order' control.

I am curious how would the community solve this kind of task? I feel like there is an approach for solving this type of problem, that's why I don't want to go straightforward and write code like:

```
if (sortingRules[0] == "s") ...
```

I am using C++11 along with Qt 5.4. No boost.

Comment: Are you going to make struct arrays with your struct variables?

Comment: @bobtheboy I think no. I just tried to give a generic example. Actually, I have a set of classes that have interface which provides methods like "int stars()", "int freeRoomCount()" and "int parkingPlacesAvailable()". When I populate the UI List View with these classes, I should rely on "std::string" sorting rule.

Comment: Can you use std::sort?  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ shows how to use a compare function, and your sorting rules string could be used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a map between their choice and a functor to sort by, for example

```
using SortFun = bool(*)(Hotel const&, Hotel const&);
std::map<char, SortFun> sorters {
    {'s', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.stars < rhs.stars; }},
    {'f', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.freeRoomCount < rhs.freeRoomCount; }},
    {'p', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.parkingPlacesAvailable < rhs.parkingPlacesAvailable; }}
};
```

Then you can use it by asking the user to input the sort criteria key, and then you can lookup the correct lambda to sort by using [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort). For the combinations of sort criteria, e.g. `"ps"`, you can loop over each sort key and `std::stable_sort` consecutively in reverse order.

```
int main()
{
    using SortFun = bool(*)(Hotel const&, Hotel const&);
    std::map<char, SortFun> sorters {
        {'s', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.stars < rhs.stars; }},
        {'f', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.freeRoomCount < rhs.freeRoomCount; }},
        {'p', [](Hotel const& lhs, Hotel const& rhs){ return lhs.parkingPlacesAvailable < rhs.parkingPlacesAvailable; }}
    };

    std::vector<Hotel> hotels {{"foo", 5, 4, 10},
                               {"bar", 3, 8, 20},
                               {"baz", 4, 5, 15},
                               {"fab", 3, 6, 18}};

    std::string choice;
    std::cout << "Pick a sort criteria s, f, p: ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    for (auto rit = choice.rbegin(); rit != choice.rend(); ++rit)
    {
        auto match = sorters.find(*rit);
        if (match != sorters.end())
        {
            std::stable_sort(begin(hotels), end(hotels), match->second);
        }
    }

    for(auto const& hotel : hotels)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << hotel.name << " Stars: " << hotel.stars << " Rooms: " << hotel.freeRoomCount << " Parking: " << hotel.parkingPlacesAvailable << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output would be ([working demo](http://cpp.sh/2euu))

```
Pick a sort criteria s, f, p: sf
Name: fab Stars: 3 Rooms: 6 Parking: 18
Name: bar Stars: 3 Rooms: 8 Parking: 20
Name: baz Stars: 4 Rooms: 5 Parking: 15
Name: foo Stars: 5 Rooms: 4 Parking: 10
```

To sort from highest to lowest, just switch all the `<` to `>` in the lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I like this C++11 solution!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a simple parser that reads a character, applies an `std::stable_sort` with the character's associated comparison predicate and proceeds to the next character.

The stable_sort part is really important. This means that if you sort the items by star count first, then by parking space, the order of star count will remain.

Comment: That's how I would do it, too. All you need is a function that has a switch based on a single character code for how to sort; you may consider doing the first sort unstable as a possible optimization (if you frequently sort by one key, or if there are a lot of repeated keys)